# Scrollview textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I copied a large text on some website and I want to show it on a single text view.
on the ADT.

It shows correct on eclipse (adt)

([Docs1](http://i40.tinypic.com/inv69x.png))

then on my tab. (exported apk)

([Docs2](http://i39.tinypic.com/29l1r3p.png))

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#02222f"

>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="
        Audio
        Android's audio Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) connects the higher level, audio-specific framework APIs in android.media to the underlying audio driver and hardware.\n

        The following figure and list describe how audio functionality is implemented and the relevant source code that is involved in the implementation.

        Application framework
        At the application framework level is the app code, which utilizes the android.media APIs to interact with the audio hardware. Internally, this code calls corresponding JNI glue classes to access the native code that interacts with the audio hardware.

        JNI
        The JNI code associated with android.media is located in the frameworks/base/core/jni/ and frameworks/base/media/jni directories. This code calls the lower level native code to obtain access to the audio hardware.

        Native framework
        The native framework is defined in frameworks/av/media/libmedia and provides a native equivalent to the android.media package. The native framework calls the Binder IPC proxies to obtain access to audio-specific services of the media server.

        Binder IPC
        The Binder IPC proxies facilitate communication over process boundaries. They are located in the frameworks/av/media/libmedia directory and begin with the letter I.

        Media Server
        The audio services in the media server, located in frameworks/av/services/audioflinger, is the actual code that interacts with your HAL implementations.

        HAL
        The HAL defines the standard interface that audio services call into and that you must implement to have your audio hardware function correctly. The audio HAL interfaces are located in hardware/libhardware/include/hardware. See audio.h for additional details.

        Kernel Driver
        The audio driver interacts with the hardware and your implementation of the HAL. You can choose to use ALSA, OSS, or a custom driver of your own at this level. The HAL is driver-agnostic."/>


</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that why it shows correct on eclipse while on my tab it shows wrong?

Comment: why don't you use the values xml for strings ?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a problem with the line end character. you are probably developing on a windows machine and running on a physical machine which is linux based.

the simple fix would be to add `\n` to the end of each line to force the system to print a new line character correctly.

Also you should use the 'string.xml' file for this, but you will still need to use the same fix